# How to make one shot timer function in Delphi (like setTimeout in JavaScript)?

Tags: delphi

The [`setTimeout`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) is helpful in JavaScript language. How would you create this function in delphi ?

```
SetTimeOut(procedure (Sender: TObject);
begin
  Self.Counter := Self.Counter + 1;
end, 200);
```

Comment: I can't  make sense of this. Could you try to elaborate please.

Comment: You want a quick and dirty one-shot timer. And then you can wrap it up in a setTimeout function for convenience.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I think you may leave the [`TTimer`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ExtCtrls.TTimer) as it is and try to use the [`SetTimer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644906%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function and use its callback function. You need to store the timer IDs and their (anonymous) methods in some collection. Since you didn't mentioned your Delphi version I've used a simple classes and [`TObjectList`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Contnrs.TObjectList) as a collection.

The principle is easy, you just call the [`SetTimer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644906%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function with the callback function specified and store the new instantiated system timer ID with the anonymous method into the collection. When that callback function is performed, find the timer which caused that callback in the collection by its ID, kill it, execute the anonymous method and delete it from the collection. Here is the sample code:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, ExtCtrls, StdCtrls, Contnrs;

type
  TOnTimerProc = reference to procedure;
  TOneShotTimer = class
    ID: UINT_PTR;
    Proc: TOnTimerProc;
  end;
  procedure SetTimeout(AProc: TOnTimerProc; ATimeout: Cardinal);

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Timer1: TTimer;
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  TimerList: TObjectList;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TimerProc(hwnd: HWND; uMsg: UINT; idEvent: UINT_PTR;
  dwTime: DWORD); stdcall;
var
  I: Integer;
  Timer: TOneShotTimer;
begin
  for I := 0 to TimerList.Count - 1 do
  begin
    Timer := TOneShotTimer(TimerList[I]);
    if Timer.ID = idEvent then
    begin
      KillTimer(0, idEvent);
      Timer.Proc();
      TimerList.Delete(I);
      Break;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure SetTimeout(AProc: TOnTimerProc; ATimeout: Cardinal);
var
  Timer: TOneShotTimer;
begin
  Timer := TOneShotTimer.Create;
  Timer.ID := SetTimer(0, 0, ATimeout, @TimerProc);
  Timer.Proc := AProc;
  TimerList.Add(Timer);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SetTimeout(procedure
    begin
      ShowMessage('OnTimer');
    end,
    1000
  );
end;

initialization
  TimerList := TObjectList.Create;
  TimerList.OwnsObjects := True;

finalization
  TimerList.Free;

end.
```

***Simplified version (Delphi 2009 up):***

Like suggested by @David's comment, here is the same code as above, just in a separate unit with the use of generics dictionary. Usage of the `SetTimeout` from this unit is same as in the above code:

```
unit OneShotTimer;

interface

uses
  Windows, Generics.Collections;

type
  TOnTimerProc = reference to procedure;
  procedure SetTimeout(AProc: TOnTimerProc; ATimeout: Cardinal);

var
  TimerList: TDictionary<UINT_PTR, TOnTimerProc>;

implementation

procedure TimerProc(hwnd: HWND; uMsg: UINT; idEvent: UINT_PTR;
  dwTime: DWORD); stdcall;
var
  Proc: TOnTimerProc;
begin
  if TimerList.TryGetValue(idEvent, Proc) then
  try
    KillTimer(0, idEvent);
    Proc();
  finally
    TimerList.Remove(idEvent);
  end;
end;

procedure SetTimeout(AProc: TOnTimerProc; ATimeout: Cardinal);
begin
  TimerList.Add(SetTimer(0, 0, ATimeout, @TimerProc), AProc);
end;

initialization
  TimerList := TDictionary<UINT_PTR, TOnTimerProc>.Create;
finalization
  TimerList.Free;

end.
```

Comment: You need to run that loop backwards because you delete from the list you iterate over

Comment: @David, not necessary here. I'm deleting just one item and breaking the loop.

Comment: I beg your pardon. Missed the break. +1. I would move the class declaration into implementation setion for better encapsulation.

Comment: @David, could be, or even better might be to move it all into a separate unit.

Comment: separate unit and a dictionary instead of object list would be ideal

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
type
TMyProc = Procedure of Object(Sender: TObject);

TMyClass = Object
    HandlerList = TStringList;
    TimerList = TStringlist;

  Procedure CallThisFunction(Sender :TObject); 

  function setTimeout(Timeout: Integer; ProcToCall : TMyProc)

end;






function setTimeout(Timeout: Integer; ProcToCall : TMyProc)
var
  Timer : TTimer;
begin

  Timer := TTimer.Create(nil);
  Timer.OnTimer := CallOnTimer;
  Timer.Interval := Timeout;
  Timer.Enabled := true;
  HandlerList.AddObject(ProcToCall);
  TimerList.AddObject(ProcToCall);

end;


function CallOnTimer(Sender : TObject)
var TimerIndex : Integer;
    HandlerToCall : TMyProc;
    Timer : TTimer;
begin

TimerIndex :=   TimerList.IndexOfObject(Sender);
HandlerToCall := (HandlerList.Objects[TimerIndex] as TMyProc) ;

HandlerToCall(Self);

HandlerList.Delete(TimerIndex);
Timer := (TimerList.Objects(TimerIndex) as TTimer);
Timer.Free;
TimerList.Delete(TimerIndex);


end;
```

This has just been hacked together and not tested in any way but shows the concept.  Basically build a list of the timers and procedures you want to call.  As it is the self object is passed to the procedure when it is called but you could build a third list that contained the object to be used as a parameter in the call to setTimeout.

The Objects are then cleaned up by freeing after the method has been called.

Not quite the same as javascripts setTimeout but a delphi approximation.

ps.  I haven't really moved on from Delphi7 so if there is a new fangled way of doing this in Delphi XE I don't know about it.

Comment: no,i want to use [anonymous function](http://delphi.about.com/od/objectpascalide/a/understanding-anonymous-methods-in-delphi.htm). your code use method pointer.

Answer (score 1):

I usually do this way

```
TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(procedure begin
  Sleep(1000); // timeout

  // put here what you want to do

end).Start;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, the function is to be called once and not 5 times every second, maybe like that:

```
 Parallel.Async( 
       procedure; begin
           Sleep(200);
           Self.Counter:=Self.Counter+1; end; );
```

There are more complex solutions like the one you accepted, taking named objects for timer actions and using SetTimer method. Like http://code.google.com/p/omnithreadlibrary/source/browse/trunk/tests/17_MsgWait/test_17_MsgWait.pas
Previous versions had SetTimer with anonymous function, but they are gone now.

However for simplistic anonymous closure approach you asked for, maybe Wait(xxX) would fit.

Answer (score 0):

My implementation of OneShotTimer Unit, with crossplatform support,
tested with Delphi XE8, firemonkey

```
unit OneShotTimerUnit;

interface

uses System.SysUtils, System.Classes, FMX.Types;

// TOneshotTimer class by Aleshkov A.F.
//
// Use one of two constructors:
//
// 1. TOneShotTimer.Create(Owner, Interval, NotifyEvent)
// creates timer with link to NotifyEvent - procedure of object
//
// 2. TOneShotTimer.Create(Owner, Interval, Proc)
// creates timer with link to Procedure (without object)
// you also can use construction like a
// TOneShotTimer.Create(Form1,1000,procedure
// begin
// {Do something}
// end);
// 
// *append. answer to @delphirules. What to do if necessary 
// to call function or procedure with parameters? 
// You can use construction like a:
// TOneShotTimer.Create(Form1,1000,procedure
// begin {Your function or procedure with parameters} end);
//
// TOneShotTimer.Create(Form1,1000,beep); //this example make a system sound after 1 sec
//
// TOneShotTimer selfdestroy after interval
// you dont need to call 'Free' method, but if close your app before timer is finished
// and Owner of timer is nil or non-existent object - you get memory leak
// so, always set Owner reference to main form of your application
//
// You also can create SetTimeout method in your form
//
// procedure TForm1.SetTimeout(AInterval: Cardinal; proc: TProc);
// begin
//   TOneshotTimer.Create(self,AInterval,proc);
// end;

type
  TOneShotTimer = class(TTimer)
  private
    FProc:TProc;
    procedure DefaultEvent(Sender:TObject);
  protected
    procedure DoOnTimer; override;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent; AInterval:Cardinal; AEvent:TNotifyEvent); reintroduce; overload;
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent; AInterval:Cardinal; AProc:TProc); reintroduce; overload;
  end;


implementation

{ TOneShotTimer }

constructor TOneShotTimer.Create(AOwner: TComponent; AInterval:Cardinal;
  AEvent: TNotifyEvent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  Interval:=AInterval;
  OnTimer:=AEvent;
  Enabled:=true;
end;

constructor TOneShotTimer.Create(AOwner: TComponent; AInterval: Cardinal;
  AProc: TProc);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  Interval:=AInterval;
  FProc:=AProc;
  OnTimer:=DefaultEvent;
  Enabled:=true;
end;

procedure TOneShotTimer.DefaultEvent(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if assigned(FProc) then FProc;
end;

procedure TOneShotTimer.DoOnTimer;
begin
  inherited;
  self.Free;
end;


end.
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This works but what if the function i want to call, has parameters ?

Comment: @delphirules Good question. You can use construction like a `TOneShotTimer.Create(Form1,1000,procedure begin {your function or procedure with parameters}; end);`. Or set your own type of function or procedure, just change TProc to custom type like a `TPredicate<T> = reference to function (Arg1: T): Boolean;`