# Height is not changed for a panel with AutoSize=true in form OnShow event

Tags: delphi, vcl

I have a panel which its **AutoSize** is true.

```
procedure TfrmIntDetails.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  MyPanel.AutoSize:= true;
end;
```

Its content is dynamically displayed or hidden in form OnShow event. So its height is changed.

```
procedure TfrmIntDetails.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Button1InsideMyPanel.visible:= true;
  Button2InsideMyPanel.visible:= false;

  //MyPanel height is changed but Height property does not updated
  PanelHeight:= MyPanel.Height; 
end;
```

I can get new height after form completely loaded (like following) but the problem is its height does not changed in OnShow event.

```
procedure TfrmIntDetails.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  PanelHeight:= MyPanel.Height;
end;
```

**Q**: I need a way to force MyPanel to update its height according to its content (e.g post a message) inside OnShow event.

Comment: can not reproduce. in Delphi5 and XE2, PanelHeight is updated in the "OnShow event".

Comment: [`I would do this`](http://pastebin.com/UrPWbnzd).

Answer (score 2):

To post a message inside your `OnShow` event, you could use @MasonWheeler's [delayedAction](http://tech.turbu-rpg.com/454/delayed-action-revisited) implementation.

It takes a reference to an anonymous procedure and puts it on the windows message queue with a `PostMessage` call.

Example:

```
DelayExec( // Puts an anonymous procedure on the message queue
  procedure
  begin
    PanelHeight := MyPanel.Height;
  end
);
```

Behind the scenes is a windows handle to post the messages to, and logic for removing the extra reference to the anonymous procedure.

**Update**

You mention that the suggested solution does not work.
If there are pending paint operations on the form, it might be a good idea to wait for them to be completed before updating your `PanelHeight` property.

Here is what to do:

```
DelayExec( // Puts an anonymous procedure on the message queue
  procedure
  var
    Msg: TMsg;
  begin
    // Make sure all pending paint messages are executed
    while PeekMessage(Msg, 0, WM_PAINT, WM_PAINT, PM_REMOVE) do
      DispatchMessage(Msg);

    PanelHeight := MyPanel.Height;
  end
);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tested this but didn't work. The procedure executed but the height is not changed.

Comment: So a PostMessage inside the `OnShow` event did not solve your problem. Have you tried to put the call inside the `TForm.OnResize` event?

Comment: No, don't work. The returned height is just as the design time height.

Comment: The question asked limits the options to answer. It seems it is not possible to solve with a `PostMessage` in the `OnShow` event. I suggest you make a new question and provide a minimal application that expresses the problem and what you have done to solve it.

Comment: I've provided `PostMessage` as a sample solution ( as I said: _"e.g post a message"_) and don't limit it (I did think its can be solved by a `PostMessage`). Sorry for disrupting you.

Comment: My comment was only a way to move the question forward. Without a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) it is difficult to answer your question.

Comment: Why to overcomplicate this task by that `DelayExec` (which will btw. leak every `PProc` instance when the message pump is full) ? I would move that code into a method called also from a custom message handler and post such message from the `OnShow` event.

Comment: @TLama, clearly there is a race between messages here. Would your proposal change the timing of this race?

Comment: @TLama, in a comment (now deleted), the OP said that it works with a call from a timer with 1 ms interval.

Comment: @LU RD, I can't think of any case when you'd need some *magical* delay (though I've met it used in some crappy code a few times). I haven't tested this case but which of the actions shown in the code would enqueue a message after your own one posted at the end of the event ?

Comment: @TLama, I have no idea, perhaps in code we cannot see. Anyway this one-shot timer might be a good solution :), [One-Shot Timers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13944475/576719).

Comment: @LU RD, I believe no timer is a solution :)

Comment: SAMpro, you can try to call Self.Update in the `OnShow` event before calling DelayExec.

Comment: @TLama - It's not the magical delay that makes it work, it's that the WM_TIMER is a posted message. The timer solution is as good as the PostMessage solution (if not better - no need for an own message), interval is irrelevant.

Comment: @Sertac, there might be a radical difference between a custom message and `WM_TIMER`, in priority. As you know, `WM_TIMER` is posted when there are no other higher priority messages in the queue, whilst custom message is enqueued as is. So I wouldn't personally compare those ways. You use timer when you need some delay, which should not be needed for this question. That was my initial point. As I got it, OP has some trouble with a control that is not realigned immediately in that event and I don't want to believe that just a self-posted message wouldn't workaround this problem.

Comment: @TLama - The radical difference is that the timer messages gets processed last. For this problem this is not a bad thing, or a disadvantage at all.. I didn't say posting a custom message wouldn't work. No one said that as I understand it. What I said is it has nothing to do with a magical delay.

Comment: However I can't argue if you find using a timer is semantically inappropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this code:

```
procedure TfrmIntDetails.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Button1InsideMyPanel.visible:= true;
  Button2InsideMyPanel.visible:= false;

  //MyPanel height is changed but Height property does not updated
  PanelHeight:= MyPanel.Height; 
  MyPanel.Height:=1; // This forces the panel to auto size
  PanelHeight:= MyPanel.Height; // Re check the value and see it has changed (it will be greater than 1 if MyPanel.AutoSize = true)
end;
```

Comment: My problem is "... its height does not changed in OnShow event."