# Create and run TTimer in runtime

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I'm trying to achieve in Delphi a behavior similar to Javascript's `setTimeout()` procedure : run things after a delay of some seconds. To do so, I'm creating a `TTimer` at runtime, running it, and then free it.

Here is my code:

```
procedure createAndRunTimer();
  procedure goTimer(Sender: TObject);
  begin
    (sender as ttimer).enabled := false;
    // do stuff here
    sender.free;
  end;
var
  t : TTimer;
begin
  t := TTimer.Create(frmprinc);
  t.Interval := 5000;
  t.OnTimer := goTimer(t);
end;
```

But my code won't compile, the compiler returns the error below:

> [DCC Error] unit1.pas(2153): E2010 Incompatible types: 'TNotifyEvent' and 'procedure, untyped pointer or untyped parameter'"

Any hints?

Comment: The error message means what it says.  See the OLH for the definition of TNotifyEvent.  You can't use a nested procedure as one.

Comment: Thanks, i moved the procedure outside the main procedure, but the error remains

Comment: TNotifyEvent is a `procedure of object`, in other words, it needs to be a  method of a class, **not** a stand-along procedure, which is what I imagine you've turned it into.

Comment: Do not "sender.free"! See documentation for "free".

Comment: See answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10468787/243614) question.

Comment: It's not gong to work. You'd need a message loop. But it's probably the wrong solution anyway.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`TNotifyEvent` is declared as:

```
TNotifyEvent = procedure(Sender: TObject) of object;
```

The `of object` makes it a **closure**, which is a special type of method pointer that carries 2 pointers - an pointer to an object, and a pointer to a non-static class method which gets called on the object.  As such, you cannot assign a standalone function, and certainly not a nested function, directly to a `TNotifyEvent`.  That is what the compiler is complaining about.

So, you need to declare a class to wrap your `OnTimer` event handler, eg:

```
type
  TTimerEvents = class
  public
    procedure goTimer(Sender: TObject);
  end;

procedure TTimerEvents.goTimer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  (Sender as TTimer).Enabled := false;

  // do stuff here

  // NOTE: you cannot destroy the Sender object from here, you must delay
  // the destruction until after this handler exits!  You can post a
  // custom window message via PostMessage() and have the message handler
  // call Sender.Free().  Or, you can use a worker thread to call
  // Sender.Free() via TThread.Synchronize() (or TThread.Queue() in Delphi
  // 8 and later).  Or, in Delphi 10.2 Tokyo and later, you can call
  // Sender.Free() via TThread.ForceQueue().  Or, use whatever other
  // mechanism you want to use to call Sender.Free(), as long as it works
  // asynchronously and calls Sender.Free() in the same thread that
  // constructed the TTimer object ...
end;

var
  events: TTimerEvents;

procedure createAndRunTimer();
var
  t : TTimer;
begin
  t := TTimer.Create(frmprinc);
  t.Interval := 5000;
  t.OnTimer := events.goTimer;
  t.Enabled := True;
end;

initialization
  events := TTimerEvents.Create;
finalization
  events.Free;
```

Alternatively, you can use a `class` method so you don't need an actual instance of the wrapper class:

```
type
  TTimerEvents = class
  public
    class procedure goTimer(Sender: TObject);
  end;

class procedure TTimerEvents.goTimer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  (Sender as TTimer).Enabled := false;

  // do stuff here

  // delay-destroy the Sender as needed ...
end;

procedure createAndRunTimer();
var
  t : TTimer;
begin
  t := TTimer.Create(frmprinc);
  t.Interval := 5000;
  t.OnTimer := TTimerEvents.goTimer;
  t.Enabled := True;
end;
```

Or, in Delphi 2006 and later, you can use a [class helper](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Class_and_Record_Helpers_(Delphi)):

```
type
  TTimerHelper = class helper for TTimer
  public
    procedure goTimer(Sender: TObject);
  end;

procedure TTimerHelper.goTimer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  (Sender as TTimer).Enabled := false;

  // do stuff here

  // delay-destroy the Sender as needed ...
end;

procedure createAndRunTimer();
var
  t : TTimer;
begin
  t := TTimer.Create(frmprinc);
  t.Interval := 5000;
  t.OnTimer := t.goTimer;
  t.Enabled := True;
end;
```

That being said, there *IS* a way to use a standalone function without using any class wrapper at all:

```
procedure goTimer(Self: Pointer; Sender: TObject);
begin
  (Sender as TTimer).Enabled := false;

  // do stuff here

  // delay-destroy the Sender as needed ...
end;

procedure createAndRunTimer();
var
  t : TTimer;
  event : TNotifyEvent;
begin
  t := TTimer.Create(frmprinc);
  t.Interval := 5000;

  TMethod(event).Data := nil; // or whatever you want to pass to the Self parameter...
  TMethod(event).Code := @goTimer;
  t.OnTimer := event;

  t.Enabled := True;
end;
```

Comment: The q is tagged `delphi-7` so why would `CreateAnonymousThread` be applicable?

Comment: @MartynA I was simply providing multiple options, as other readers may be using more modern versions of Delphi.  I've reworded it for you.

Answer (score -1):

I've used this procedure from Torry's as a delay, it doesn't lock the thread while executing:

```
procedure Delay(dwMilliseconds: Longint);
var
  iStart, iStop: DWORD;
begin
  iStart := GetTickCount;
  repeat
    iStop := GetTickCount;
    Application.ProcessMessages;
    Sleep(1);
  until (iStop - iStart) >= dwMilliseconds;
end;
```

Comment: Calling `ProcessMessages()` in a tight loop is always a bad idea. I have written similar loops before, but I would at least use `GetQueueStatus()` or `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects()` to know when `ProcessMessages()` actually needs to be called and when it can be skipped. However, in this situation, I would suggest using a [waitable timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687012.aspx) with `WaitForSingleObject()`/`MsgWaitForMultipleObjects()` or `RegisterWaitForSingleObject()`, instead of using `GetTickCount()` and `Sleep()` at all.