# TTask run lifetime or while he should still active

Tags: delphi

How i can add some ttasks and their tasks works lifetime or while a variable still true?
example i create the taks here (2 tasks)

```
var
  Tasks : array [0..1] of ITask;
  x     : Integer;
begin
  for x := 0 to 1 do
  begin
    Tasks[x] := TTask.Create(ManageEvent(x));
    Tasks[x].Start;
  end;
```

the manage event routine is:

```
    function ManageEvent(ID : Integer): TProc;
begin
  TLabel(Form1.FindComponent(Events[ID][4])).Caption := Format('%s', [Events[ID][0]]);

  TLabel(Form1.FindComponent(Events[ID][5])).Caption := FormatDateTime('hh:nn:ss', StrToTime(Events[ID][1]) - Time);
  TLabel(Form1.FindComponent(Events[ID][5])).Repaint;
end;
```

Events are declared as:

```
Events : Array [0..1, 0..6] of String = (('Event A - 22:54:00', '22:54:00', 'ON', '0', 'Label1', 'Label4', 'Image13'),
                                            ('Event B - 22:54:00', '22:54:00', 'OFF', '0', 'Label2', 'Label5', 'Image14'));
```

What i need is their taks run lifetime, or while their threads (ttasks) still alive, so they update the labels setup ar Events array with the actually time and the difference of time between set at array and actual time.

how i can do that? to these tasks works lifetime or while still active?

Comment: Your `ManageEvent()` is declared as returning a `TProc` but does not actually return anything. You probably meant to put the code inside of `ManageEvent` into an anonymous procedure and then return that. But even if it did, `TTask` runs in a worker thread, and the code inside of `ManageEvent()` is not thread-safe and must be synchronized with the main UI thread using `TThread.Synchronize()` or `TThread.Queue()`. And you need to make the `TTask` proc run a loop if you want it to update the UI over time, like a timer (why are you not simply using actual timers, like `TTimer`?)

Comment: Solved using https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49637129/create-and-run-ttimer-in-runtime